# Stripping all WS chars in a python script doesn't work

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, removing-whitespace

I tried the following in my python interpreter (v2.7.1 on Mac OSX 10.7.5):

```
s = " \n \t abc\t\n def \t"
t = "".join(s.strip())
abcdef
```

Yet, when I run the same join() statement in a *.py script, it doesn't strip all WS chars:

result:  `abc\t\n def`

What's going on to cause this discrepancy?

Answer (score 1):

[`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) strips at the beginning and at the end of the string.

```
>>> s = " \n \t abc\t\n def \t"
>>> s.strip()
'abc\t\n def'
```

I think you meant [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> s = " \n \t abc\t\n def \t"
>>> s.split()
['abc', 'def']
>>> ''.join(s.split())
'abcdef'
```

Comment: That's what I meant.  However, that still doesn't fix the problem I'm seeing.

Comment: @CM, Did you replace `strip` with `split` ?

Comment: Yes, I did.  Still doesn't work.  At least in the script.  If I do in the interpreter, split() works

Comment: @CM, How doesn't it work? It does not print anything? It raises an exception? It does print something different from what you want?

Comment: The latter result:

in the interpreter, it's as you wrote.
in the script, the result is '\n\tabc\t\ndef\t'

So it seems only the space chars are the only things getting stripped out

Comment: @CM, Possible cause is that you're printing the original value instead of the replaced one. Try `s = ''.join(s.split())` (Assign replaced string back to the original variable)

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python

import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print ("only one string per customer")
    exit -1

    #phase 1:  strip WS chars
s = sys.argv[1]
t = ''.join(s.split())
print "stripped arg: ", t

Comment: @CM, There are no parentheses in `exit -1`. Is that a typo?

Comment: @CM, If you mean you're passing a string from the shell: `python your_script.py '\n\tabc\t\ndef\t'`, those `\n`, `\t` are not newline, tab characters, but literally a backslash and `n`/`t`. They are passed as is from the shell.

Comment: Hi there.  Adding the extra s.decode('string-escape').split() worked!  Great find, thanks!